# Web page wider than all screens, including desktop

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

Like the title says, my webpage is wider than all screens. I inspected it and the `<html>` element is a few pixels to skinny for every screen. I don't know what is causing this, I have a `<meta>` tag to control the viewport but that hasn't solved the problem.

This page is at [site.dev.genuinesolar.com](https://site.dev.genuinesolar.com)

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden` on body may solve your problem

Comment: Add css to `div#root {
}`

Comment: Adding `overflow-x: hidden` to `#root` fixes it. I appreciate it.